# trouble installing SQLite

Tags: raspbian-jessie, sqlite

using a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian Jessie I get this error when installing sqlite3 with

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
>    sqlite3 : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.7.1-1+deb8u2) but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Gives me this error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Correcting dependencies... Done
>   The following extra packages will be installed:
>     libgcc1
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     libgcc1
>   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   2 not fully installed or removed.
>   Need to get 0 B/39.5 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 160 kB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
>   debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:armhf:
>    libc6:armhf depends on libgcc1; however:
>     Package libgcc1 is not installed.
>   dpkg: error processing package libc6:armhf (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
>    multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.13-5); however:
>     Package libc6:armhf is not configured yet.
>   dpkg: error processing package multiarch-support (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    libc6:armhf
>    multiarch-support
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Can anyone help me out please?

Edit update:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install debconf
```

gives me this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
>              Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
>              Recommends: debconf-i18n but it is not going to be installed
>    libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Keeps giving the same 'dependency' error as above

Comment: yes I did, update and upgrade

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to examine this way what has gone wrong. I do not use oldstable `jessie` anymore. Your updated question shows that there are newer versions of some libraries expected. This I've seen when I tried to install packets from [debian backports](https://backports.debian.org/). But this is not a cause here. Next I would look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` where to get packets. On 2018-03-13 we had a big upgrade on `stretch` from 2017-11-29. Maybe this is affected to `jessie`? Is it an option to switch to `stretch`?

Comment: security support for oldstable Jessie ends May 2018 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_table

Comment: I started over with a 'virgin' stretch and it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to `stretch` solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is

> E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?

This is needed to configure installed packets. Check if it is available:

```
rpi3 ~$ debconf --help
```

Check if it is installed:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt update
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi3 ~$ apt list debconf
```

If not installed:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt install debconf
```

If installed, try to reinstall it:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt --reinstall install debconf
```

Comment: debconf is installed but I get new errors. Pretty hard to post them here with the formatting in comments. Any suggestions how I can post these errors?

Comment: Edit your question e.g. with remark "Update:"